# captcha on stream post

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

As of last night, facebook seems to be automatically popping up a captcha for any stream post from my application.  This is for stream posts to my own wall as well as my friends wall.  All of the stream posts link back to http://apps.facebook.com/fortyhumans with some addition params for analytics tracking.  So I do not believe I am violating the requirement that links must point to the app canvas or website url.

I'm using the following code to do the post.

```
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: '',
        attachment: {
            name: sName,
            caption: sCaption,
            description: (sDescription),
            href: sHrefLink,
            media: [{'type':'image', 'src':sImgSrc, 'href':sHrefLink}]
            },
        action_links: [
            { text: sHrefTitle, href: sHrefLink }
        ],
        user_prompt_message: sUserPrompt
    },
```

Is there any way to avoid this captcha from popping up?  Should I be posting using a different api?  The user experience with captchas is very poor.  Even posting to my own wall pops up a captcha.

I've read in previous posts here that some people changed to using a bit.ly url or something similar.  But that would seem to violate the requirement that links in stream posts must point to canvas or website url.

Any help would be appreciated, or if this is not the right place then where should a question like this be posted.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well since I changed my Fb like button to iframe a couple of days ago, and I don't know how to fix it and I don't know if it was because of that change or not, but i would like to know. I even clicked on the button that says "I'm viewing this(captcha) by mistake" but I think they'll not respond to that even I did mentioned that I am the owner of the website.